# Python json.py can't convert string to dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to put a dictionary into a `.txt` file, and then using `json.load(File.read())` parse the string to a dictionary.

For some reason it is not working.

CODE:

```
import json
File = open(r"{}.txt".format(path), 'w')
File.write(json.dumps({"Key":"Value"}))
File.close()
#There the .txt file is {'Key':'Value'}
File = open(r"{}.txt".format(path), 'r')
Dictionary = json.loads(File.read())
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    json.loads(FIle.read())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But when I do this:

```
>>> json.dumps({"Key":"Value"})
'{"Key": "Value"}'
>>> json.loads('{"Key": "Value"}')
{'Key': 'Value'}
>>>
```

nothing wents wrong.

Why does it happen? Thank you in advance for answering.

### Edit

---

Thanks a lot for who in the comments suggested me to use `json.load()`, it worked.

```
>>> json.load(open(r"C:\\Users\FLAK-ZOSO\Desktop\mlmlm.txt", 'r+'))
{'Key': 'Value'}
>>> Dictionary = json.load(open(r"C:\\Users\WouldYouLikeToKnow\Desktop\mlmlm.txt", 'r+'))
>>> Dictionary
{'Key': 'Value'}
```

The problem was that the file results empty because before `File.close()` the edits aren't saved.
Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: ```.read``` method may add an extra ```'\n'``` character indicating new line. You may want to strip that using ```.strip("\n")```

Comment: There is another method (`json.load()`) that accepts a file. You can just do `json.load(File)`. There is also a similar method for writing to a file: `json.dump(File, data)`

Comment: That code doesn't create that error.

Comment: The traceback shows `FIle.read()`, rather than `File.read()` - are you sure you're reading from the file you think you are, and not some previously-opened file that happens to be empty?

Comment: @Sujay `read` doesn't do that. And even if it did, why not simply let `loads` ignore it?

Comment: @jasonharper that's because I copy pasted the error from an other shell, but the only difference (I'm pretty sure) is that typo error (FIle instead of File)

Comment: @12944qwerty Thank you, your json.load() worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json` library has more methods than only `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`.

---

- `json.dumps` stands for `dump-s` where `s` stands for `string`
- `json.loads` stands for `load-s` where `s` stands for `string`

In fact this two methods are returning or passing as parameter a `string`-type.

```
>>> json.dumps({1: 'a', 2: 'b'}) #Needs as parameter an object or a value
'{"1": "a", "2": "b"}' #Returns a string
>>> json.loads('{"1": "a", "2": "b"}') #Needs as parameter a string
{'1': 'a', '2': 'b'} #Parses an object or returns a value
```

---

- `json.dump` writes to a file specified as the second argument (`.txt` or `.json`) the first argument passed
- `json.load` reads from a file (`.txt` or `.json`) passed as the first argument

This two methods are reading or writing to a `.json` file.

```
>>> json.dumps({1: 'a'}, open('file.json', 'w+'))
>>> json.load(open('file.json', 'r'))
{'1': 'a'} #Returns an object or a value
```

---

So, in order to avoid raising errors, you can avoid doing this:

```
value = json.loads(open('file.json', 'r').read()) #Shouldn't do this
value = json.load(open('file.json', 'r')) #Much better, more efficient and it doesn't raise any error
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have reputation to comment I'm writing this as an answer. I tried to run your erroring code on my machine and it had no problems with it whatsoever (provided I replace path with something like 'check_json.json'). This tells me that it's related to your environment.

The error itself (**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**) seems to pop up when you're operating on an empty string, meaning that File.read() is returning an empty string that json.loads doesn't know what to do with.

Some possible issues could be:

1. You've redefined a reserved keyword somewhere and so Python is struggling to get the objects to behave as they should (a shot in the dark based on your use of File and Dictionary. Yes they're not builtins/reserved words but who knows what the rest of the code looks like right?)
2. Something's wrong in your Python install and you need to reinstall it.
3. You have some sort of strange permissions that stop you from actually saving down data to this file that you're creating.

Comment: It's everytime related to my enviroment  I have problems since I uninstalled python.org's python and I installed microsoft store's one...
Thank you for your answer, I upvoted it, so that the next time maybe you will be able to answer with a comment . 
I'll accept it because one of the problems was the method I used, but the other was File.read() was returning an empty string, as you guessed. Well done.